# How can I use SFINAE to create a template function for containers, and deduce the return type based on an operator?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I tried to make a 'generateCombinations' function, that would take two containers of items, and generate a container of their combinations (e.g. {"hello "}, {"world","friend"} would produce {"hello world", "hello friend"}. I was trying to use SFINAE, and decltype on the operator+() to deduce the return type, but I've gotten many many errors, with many different attempts. Here is the current version:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename S>
using CombinationResult = decltype(operator+(T(),S()));

template<typename T, typename S>
using CombinationResultContainer = std::vector< CombinationResult<T, S>>;


template<typename T, typename S>
CombinationResultContainer<typename T::value_type,typename S::value_type> generateCombinations(T&& first, S&& second)
{
    CombinationResultContainer<typename T::value_type, typename S::value_type> result;
    result.reserve(first.size() * second.size());
    for (auto& t : first)
        for (auto& s : second)
            result.push_back(t + s);
    return result;
}



 void main()
{
    std::vector<std::string>v1;
    std::vector<std::string>v2;

    generateCombinations(v1,v2);
}
```

At the moment I get the errors:
C2672   'generateCombinations': no matching overloaded function found

C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'std::vector> generateCombinations(T &&,S &&)'

Comment: `template<typename T, typename S>
using CombinationResult = decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<S>())` to avoid the constraint of default constructible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a Cartesian product ? Try range v3’s

```
view::cartesian_product
```

Your code’s problem is that you need to remove the reference of T and S
Try

```
typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type
```

Same for S

Or

```
typename boost::range_value<T>::type
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` and `U` are not what you think. You would expect that they would both be `std::vector<std::string>`, but because of the fact that `v1` and `v2` are lvalues, this means `T` and `U` are both `std::vector<std::string>&` because of [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing). When you try to do:

```
CombinationResultContainer<typename T::value_type, typename S::value_type>
```

This will not work because `T` and `U` are not class types, but references. This is the nature of [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#t-rev%20t-since-cxx11) along side [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

Since nothing in your function relies on the fact that `T` or `U` are lvalue references or not, I would suggest you use lvalue references to const instead (`T const&` and `U const&`). This will deduce `T` and `U` as the expected types.